# How to emit messages from a Sink and pass them to another function?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am currently building a client-side WebSockets consumer using Akka-HTTP. Instead of trying to do the parsing in the Sink, I wanted to wrap the code in a function which emits the outcome from the Sink, and then use this output (from the function) later for further processing (more parsing...etc.).

I am currently able to print every message from the Sink; however, the return type of the function remains to be `Unit`. My objective is to Emit a `String` from the function, for each item that lands in the sink, and then use the returned string to do further parsing. I have the code I have so far (Note: it's mostly boiler plate).

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import akka.Done
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{Message, TextMessage, WebSocketRequest, WebSocketUpgradeResponse}
import akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ClientConnectionSettings
import akka.stream.Materializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object client extends App {

  def parseData(uri: String)(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer): Unit = {

    val defaultSettings = ClientConnectionSettings(system)
    val pingCounter = new AtomicInteger()
    val customWebsocketSettings = defaultSettings.websocketSettings.withPeriodicKeepAliveData(
      () => ByteString(s"debug-${pingCounter.incrementAndGet()}")
    )

    val customSettings = defaultSettings.withWebsocketSettings(customWebsocketSettings)

    val outgoing = Source.maybe[Message]

    val sink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach[Message] {
      case message: TextMessage.Strict => message.text // I Want to emit/stream this message as a String from the function (or get a handle on it from the outside)
      case _ => println("Other")
    }

    val webSocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]] =
      Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest(uri), settings = customSettings)

    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      outgoing
        .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right)
        .toMat(sink)(Keep.both)
        .run()


    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Future.successful(Done)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(
          s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}"
        )
      }
    }

    connected.onComplete {
      case Success(value) => value
      case Failure(exception) => throw exception
    }

    closed.onComplete { _ =>
      println("Retrying...")
      parseData(uri)
    }

    upgradeResponse.onComplete {
      case Success(value) => println(value)
      case Failure(exception) => throw exception
    }
  }
}
```

And in a seperate object, I would like to do the parsing, so something like:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.Materializer
import api.client.parseData



object Application extends App {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer: Materializer = Materializer(system)
  val uri = "ws://localhost:8080/foobar"

  val res = parseData(uri) // I want to handle the function output here 
  // parse(res)
  println(res)
```

Is there a way I can get a handle on the Sink from outside the function, or do I need to do any parsing in the Sink. I am mainly trying to not overcomplicate the Sink.

Update: I am also considering if adding another `Flow` element to the stream (which handles the parsing) is a better practice than getting values outside of the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a flow element seems to solve your problem while being totally idiomatic.

What you have to keep in mind is that the sinks semantic is meant to describe how to "terminate" the stream, so while it can describe very complex computations, it will always return a single value which is returned only once the stream ends.

Said differently, a sink does not return a value per stream element, it returns a value per whole stream.

Comment: How should I approach this if I want to pass the output from the Sink to another function? In other words, how can I make the function return/eval-to the Sink?

Comment: When you call run, it returns a future with the sink value, which you can do whatever you want with I think ?

Comment: Also, if you're dead set on streaming from the sink, you can use side-effecting techniques, like sending a message to an actor from the sink, which is still effectively unit type, but allows you to do whatever you want. It's less natural than building the flow though imo.

Comment: It seems to return a Future, but definetly not the stream output I would have expected. That makes sense given your answer (one value per stream). Thanks for bringing up the actor option! Adding a Flow seems the most natural solution.